# git push logon failed

Tags: git, authentication, github, git-bash

When I try to use Git Bash to push to git I it opens a credential prompt asking me to login to GitHub. When I correctly enter my Github password it prompts an error reading: Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt. My password was not changed recently.

I am logged into Github Desktop and it works fine. I'm obviously new to GitHub and have no idea what I could do to fix the error.

Comment: That's because of the deprecated login feature of git for https authentication, check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65331017/6281981 You can still use ssh authentication for old version of the git:
https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Answer (score 0):

probably your git remote is wrong.

you can check it by typing in

```
git remote -v
```

[Here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/using-git/adding-a-remote) you can read more

Does it help you?